# Excel Data to new SQL Server table using C# - new table not being created?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to copy data from `Excel` into a new table in `SQL Server`.

The SQL code I'm using works in Server Manager, copying data into a newly created table & does seem to work here, except the new table doesn't appear in my Database and running the code again seems to produce an `"Table already exists"` error.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Code as follows:

```
 try
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = string.Format("Data Source=XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DbName;" + "Integrated Security=SSPI; User Instance=False");
            string excelConnectionString = string.Format("provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\\user\\ExcelFileName.xlsx; Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0 xml; HDR=YES;IMEX=1'");
            using (SqlConnection SQLconnection =
                new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
            using (OleDbConnection connection =
                new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                ("SELECT * INTO dbo.newTable FROM [SheetName$];", connection);

                connection.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy =
                    new SqlBulkCopy(SQLconnection))
                {
                    bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.newTable";
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                    Console.WriteLine("The data has been exported from Excel to SQL.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: What if you don't use `dbo.` as a prefix for table name?

Comment: If I do that, the code runs OK without a 'Table already exists' error message but I still can't see the new table in SQLDb using SQL Server management studio.

Comment: Which user are you logging in as to SQL Server Management Studio? I bet it is bound to a differeny schema. Can you use same credentials as you use in connecting in code?

Comment: It must be something like that but what exactly, isn't obvious - when I create a table using SQL Server management studio, some C# code I wrote, using the same sqlConnection, successfully deletes it from my SQLDb. I've even added 'User Id & Password to the connection string but still the same error 'Table X already exists' but it doesn't appear in the Db. Queries using TempDb, Master etc also don't recognise the table as existing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi think you are not checking your table name before inserting excel data into data table. you can go through the below code.

```
class excelTwosheetsBulk1
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(excelTwosheetsBulk1));
        log.Info("Connection to database started.");
        string path = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection con;
        con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.charterConnection);
        //SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(con);
        string tableName = string.Empty;
        log.Info("Filepath has to be uploaded....");
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter complete file path including name : ");
        path = Console.ReadLine();
        log.Info("File has uploaded....");
        try
        {
            if (path == "")
            {
                log.Info("File has not uploaded.");
                Console.WriteLine("Please upload file path......");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                log.Info("Binding excel data to datatable event started.");
                DataSet ds = ReadExcelFile(path);
                log.Info("Binding excel data to datatable event ended.");
                for (int tableCount = 0; tableCount < ds.Tables.Count; tableCount++)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Contains("'"))
                    {
                        ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName = ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Replace("'", "");
                    }
                    if (ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Contains(" "))
                    {
                        ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName = ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Replace(" ", "");
                    }
                    if (ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.EndsWith("$"))
                    {
                        ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName = ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Replace("$", "");
                    }
                    if (ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.EndsWith(" "))
                    {
                        ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName = ds.Tables[tableCount].TableName.Replace(" ", "");
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
                {
                    log.Info("Creation of datatable in database.");
                    string result = string.Empty;
                    int tableCount = CheckTable(ds.Tables[i].TableName, con);
                    if (tableCount > 0)
                    {
                        result = CreateTableStatement(ds.Tables[i].TableName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy"), ds.Tables[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = CreateTableStatement(ds.Tables[i].TableName, ds.Tables[i]);
                    }
                    con.Open();
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand(result, con))
                    {
                        var r = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock | SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.UseInternalTransaction, null);
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = ds.Tables[i].TableName;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[i]);
                    tableName += result + ",";
                    con.Close();
                }
                log.Info("Excel data imported successfully into datatable.");
                Console.WriteLine("Table " + tableName.Trim(',') + " imported successfully.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Exception occoured at : " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Table " + "" + " has error while importing.");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static string CreateTableStatement(string tableName, DataTable table)
    {
        log.Info("Assigning parameters to columns.");
        string sqlsc;
        sqlsc = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(";
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            sqlsc += "\n [" + table.Columns[i].ColumnName + "] ";
            string columnType = table.Columns[i].DataType.ToString();
            switch (columnType)
            {
                case "System.Int32":
                    sqlsc += " int ";
                    break;
                case "System.Int64":
                    sqlsc += " bigint ";
                    break;
                case "System.Int16":
                    sqlsc += " smallint";
                    break;
                case "System.Byte":
                    sqlsc += " tinyint";
                    break;
                case "System.Decimal":
                    sqlsc += " decimal ";
                    break;
                case "System.DateTime":
                    sqlsc += " datetime ";
                    break;
                case "System.String":
                default:
                    sqlsc += string.Format(" nvarchar({0}) ", table.Columns[i].MaxLength == -1 ? "max" : table.Columns[i].MaxLength.ToString());
                    break;
            }
            if (table.Columns[i].AutoIncrement)
                sqlsc += " IDENTITY(" + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementSeed.ToString() + "," + table.Columns[i].AutoIncrementStep.ToString() + ") ";
            if (!table.Columns[i].AllowDBNull)
                sqlsc += " NOT NULL ";
            sqlsc += ",";
        }
        return sqlsc.Substring(0, sqlsc.Length - 1) + "\n)";
    }

    public static DataSet ReadExcelFile(string path)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string connString = "";
        try
        {
            if (path.Trim().EndsWith(".xlx"))
            {
                log.Info("Finding excel type file.");
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"";
            }
            else if (path.Trim().EndsWith(".xlsx"))
            {
                log.Info("Finding excel type file.");
                connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";
            }
            //string connectionString = GetConnectionString(path);
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                // Get all Sheets in Excel File
                log.Info("Appending names to datatable.");
                DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                // Loop through all Sheets to get data
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    log.Info("Binding excel data to datatable in sql.");
                    string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    string x = sheetName.Substring(1, sheetName.Length - 2);
                    //string x = sheetName.Trim(' ').ToString();
                    if (!x.EndsWith("$"))
                        continue;
                    // Get all rows from the Sheet
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.TableName = sheetName;
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    Console.WriteLine("Binding excel data to datatable.");
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);
                }
                cmd = null;
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Info("Error occurred at :" + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to fetch excel data.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        log.Info("Excel data has binded to datatable.");
        return ds;
    }

    private static int CheckTable(string p, SqlConnection con)
    {

        string result = "SELECT count(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = '" + p + "'";
        con.Open();

        var cmd = new SqlCommand(result, con);
        cmd.CommandText = result;
        Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();
        return count;
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string path)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
        props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0 XML";
        props["Data Source"] = path;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
        {
            sb.Append(prop.Key);
            sb.Append('=');
            sb.Append(prop.Value);
            sb.Append(';');
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```